# How to display both images and media element inside flipview in windows app 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, flipview

I am having a list which has both images and media elements and the order of these two in the list is not predictable which means there will be image after media element and even media element after image.

I would now want to show them in flipview control. As user proceeds to flip the image or media element, if current item is media and next item is image, as user proceeds to flip the item, initially it shows error loading path.

Is there any way we can handle flip view selection changing event ? We have selection changed event but not changing.

Is there anyway we could achieve this ?

Comment: So you need two different views of item depends of order of your content?

Comment: Yes.  successive items in collection will not be same always. So When we flip through the collection, we need to be able to show items without any flaws.

Answer (score 0):

Use a TemplateSelector to choose a DataTemplate based on the type of item in your collection.